# Тестовое задание

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать тестовое задание и хочу, чтобы оно выглядело примерно так: Сколько будет 2+2?

Тут будет поле для ввода цифры.

Тут будет кнопка с надписью "Ответить"  и если в поле введена цифра 4, то должно появиться окно с текстом правильно, а если не 4, а любое другое - с надписью неправильно.

Comment: А примеры откуда брать планируете? Примеров таких много или несколько? поле в всплывающем окне или просто в input'e?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = prompt("Сколько будет 2 + 2 ?");
if(parseInt(data) == 4){
    alert('Правильно!');
} else {
    alert('Не павильно, иди учись, бестолочь');
}
```

Comment: Ну если тупо для 2+2 то собственно и все, просто мне кажется  что идея ТСа не так проста, могу ошибаться конечно...

Comment: Какой вопрос - такой и ответ ;)